# HDMI port not working on HP Omen Laptop

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, hdmi

I am trying to get a second monitor to work on my new HP Omen/Ubuntu 16.04, so I can work properly on my laptop. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and I've tried several of the things suggested in similar topics, but none of them worked so far (unfortunately I didn't document the things I tried well enough, but I do remember trying different versions of the open source nvidia drivers, as well as the proprietary drivers, I also tried using xconf, but couldn't find a proper explanation on how to do it and got stuck). I have the following outputs.

`lspci -v`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
DeviceName: Intel Kabylake HD Graphics GT2
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8259
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
Memory at b2000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
Kernel modules: i915_bpo

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c8c (rev a1)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8259
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at b3000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=128]
Expansion ROM at b4000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
```

`sudo lshw -C display`:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b4000000-b407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

`xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  59.93    40.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

[Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/f4JvezwD)

In all cases I run these commands while the HDMI cable is plugged in and the second monitor is on, if that matters somehow. I'd be happy to dive deep and learn about the nuts and bolts if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work by installing the drivers downloaded from nvidia.com directly. Followed [this](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2017/05/15/how-to-install-nvidia-gtx-1050-ti-driver-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-64bit-easy-guide/) tutorial. The previous times with older versions these errored out, but this time it worked and I am now able to use a second monitor. I'm delighted!

Comment: The only thing that is still not working is the sound over HDMI. Working on that.